# Can anyone please recommend a test framework for XSLT?

Tags: xml, unit-tests, xpath

I've been using XSLT 2.0 for about 8 years now, mostly for transforming DITA into a pile of different formats. My stylesheets are getting pretty sophisticated, and my templates pretty complex at this point. The outputs I generate are for regulated medical products, and an escape can potentially be very serious.

I would like to begin automating some unit tests to help detect regressions. Python has pytest, Javascript has Jest, C# has Nunit. Is there a similar framework out there specifically for testing XSLT that you can recommend, or should I just plan to "roll my own"?

Answer (score 0):

XSpec is generally recommended.

https://xspec.io/about/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree, my answer could be improved if there were more hours in the day.